# Possible to change email from which mail is sent in workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In Sharepoint 2010 when email is sent as action, it is from `System` account. Can I change it and make it as `myemail@gmail.com`

Comment: is it  a OOB Workflow, Made in designer or in Visual Studio?

Comment: These type of questions should go on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Not with SharePoint Designer's OTB send email action. I have used Virto's SharePoint Workflow Activity Kit to solve this problem with SharePoint designer. It has a send mail action that allows you to specify the sender.

Comment: Please let me know the Source Code, If possible. or provide some link.

Comment: [link](http://www.virtosoftware.com/extended-workflow-activities-for-sharepoint-designer.aspx)